# WPDB: count number of times a particular value appears

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to count the number of times the value of "yes" appears in the column "helpful" in the table "wp_wthp_helpful_log" for the current post in the loop.

[image]

Here is what I have so far, but isn't working. Any guidance would be helpful. This is the first time I have ever tried to use wpdb.

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$helpfulcount = $wpdb->get_var(" SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {$wpdb->wp_wthp_helpful_log} WHERE post_id = $id AND helpful = 'yes' ");
if ( $helpfulcount > 0 ) {
    echo 'I got a count of '.$helpfulcount ;} else {  };
?>
```

Got it working with this...

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
global $post;
$postid = $post->ID;
$helpfulcount = $wpdb->get_var(" SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_wthp_helpful_log WHERE post_id = $postid AND helpful = 'yes' ");
if ( $helpfulcount > 0 ) {
echo 'I got a count of '.$helpfulcount ; } else {  };
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put `yes` in quotes because it's a literal string, not a name that MySQL recognizes:

```
<?php
    $helpfulcount = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {$wpdb->wp_wthp_helpful_log} WHERE postid = $id AND helpful = 'yes'");
    if ( $helpfulcount > 0 ) {
        echo 'I got a count of '.$helpfulcount ; } else {  };
?>
```

Note also the `{` and `}` around `$wpdb->wp_wthp_helpful_log`.

Comment: Thanks Ed, getting closer. I updated the original post with the modified code and an image from the DB. Now there are no errors on the page but I am still not getting any echoed value.

Comment: @mcseay are you sure your query actually matches any rows? Try running it directly (e.g., in phpMyAdmin) and see what you get.

Comment: This works in phpMyAdmin...
    SELECT * FROM `wp_wthp_helpful_log` WHERE `helpful` = 'yes'
Oddly, it seems that ' is different from `?
This statement is part of a much larger function. $id is set previously in the function.

Comment: Sorry... this works in phpMyAdmin
SELECT * FROM 'wp_wthp_helpful_log' WHERE 'helpful' = 'yes'

Comment: Figured it out... will update question with working code. Thanks!